# Is there a way to change TestNG runtime duration verbosity level?

Tags: java, testng

I am currently using the XMLReporter class in TestNG 6.9.10 to report the test results. I want to use the runtime duration to track performance, but it isn't at the level that I need.

**Current output:** There are 2 levels of duration reported. The duration of the entire suite and the duration of each test **invocation**.

**Desired output:** The **average** duration of one invocation. So if I have a test method "testMethod()" and it had 3 invocations and they took 1,2, and 3 seconds, I would like to see a property like avg-duration-ms = "2000".

Is there a convenient way to do this? Has anyone written their own listener/reporter that does this? I know that I could just write an external program to use the current output to achieve what I need, but I am wondering if there is a way to implement it within TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener which implements `ITestListener` (or just add the logic to `@AfterMethod`) with `ITestResult` collect information of current invocation duration and using `ITestNGMethod` get total invocations and current invocation number.